# Yii2 - create dropdown (select) with another model

Tags: php, yii2

At the begging of the view file I am loading model:

```
use app\models\Countries;
```

And a bit down in the code I am trying to create dropdown (model is generated via gii):

```
<?php

        echo $form->field(Countries::find()->all(), 'Country')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ['prompt'=>'Select Country']
                );

    ?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
     PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
    Call to a member function formName() on a non-object

1. in /home/sasha/Documents/Scopic/Stokkee/project/svn/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php at line 1975
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'your_field')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->all(), 'country_id', 'Country_description'),['prompt'=>'']) ?>
```

change `country_id, your_field and country_description` for your need

Comment: Yep, that's the thing I am looking for :). Thanks a lot for help.